# MongoDB secondary initial sync issue

Tags: mongodb

I have a a primary and a secondary mongo server. But since the disk space on both of them are about to fill and their is no option to increase disk size on these servers.
Database Size is 1.2 TB

I have another server which is having enough space. But when I try to start the initial sync on this server it just go into RECOVERY state after around 750 GB. Might be because it crosses oplog.

I don't even have enough space to increase oplog.

Please Suggest how can I add another server as a secondary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by transferring tar over netcat. Using this mechanism I was able to transfer huge amount of data in very short time. For more details read http://toast.djw.org.uk/tarpipe.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for Initial sync approach when data size is huge.

Please follow this procedure:

1. Add new node into `replica group`
2. Once new node joined in the replica and Immediately stop `MongoDB service` or `Mongod` process on a new node when it's going to `STARTUP2` stage.
3. Stop another secondary from current replication
4. Copy data file from existing secondary to a new node
5. start existing secondary server
6. Verify existing secondary running as a secondary
7. After verified, start MongoDB service on the new node and it will go to `RECOVERY` after it'll go `SECONDARY` stage.

This is the plan for adding a new node(via snapshot).

NOTE: If your environment have 3 node replica not required `downTime` otherwise we need `downTime`.